# How to show form when clicking buttons on nav

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm trying to make one project based on my studies and I want to use AngularJS for this website but I have a problem with nav. The forms doesn't show when I click on nav.

This is the code of nav

```
<nav>
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li><a class="active" ng-model="myVar"  value="Home" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ng-model="myVar" value="Employees" title="New Employee">Register new Employee</a></li>
    <li><a ng-model="myVar" value="Customers" title="New Customer">Register new Customer</a></li>
    <li><a ng-model="myVar" value="Members" title="New Member">Register new Member</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

and this is this is the forms which I want to be shown when I click the buttons on nav

```
<div ng-switch="myVar">

    <div ng-switch-when="Home">
                <h2>Welcome to Gate's Corporate Portal </h2>

                    <p class="pindex animated rotateIn">
                    With this online application:<br>
                    Your can add New Employees,
                    New Customers,
                    and New Members 
                    </p>

        <div ng-switch-when="Employees">

        <div class="animated fadeInDown">
                    <form method="post" >
                    <legend>Register new Employee</legend>
                    <form method="post" action="employeesaction.php" >

                        <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
                        <label for="surname">Surname:</label><input type="text" name="surname"><br><br>
                        <label for="date_of_birth">Date of Birth:</label><input type="date" name="date_of_birth"><br><br>
                        <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label><input type="text" name="telephone"><br><br>
                        <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label><input type="text" name="mobile"><br><br>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
                        <label for="address">Address:</label><input type="text" name="address"><br><br>
                        <label for="tin">Tin:</label><input type="text" name="tin"><br><br>
                        <label for="employee_id">Employee id:</label><input type="text" name="employee_id"><br><br>         

                        <p class="center"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <button class="button1 animated flipInX" type="submit" value="Submit">Register</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class="button2 animated flipInY" type="reset" value="reset">Clear form</button>     
                    </form>
                </div>
        </div>  
            <div ng-switch-when="Customers">
            <legend>Register new Customer</legend>
                    <form method="post" action="customersaction.php">

                        <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
                        <label for="surname">Surname:</label><input type="text" name="surname"><br><br>
                        <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label><input type="text" name="telephone"><br><br>
                        <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label><input type="text" name="mobile"><br><br>
                        <label for="customers_company">Customers company:</label><input type="text" name="customers_company"><br><br>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
                        <label for="address">Address:</label><input type="text" name="address"><br><br>
                        <label for="tin">Tin:</label><input type="text" name="tin"><br><br>
                        <p class="center"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <button class="button1 animated flipInX" type="submit" value="Submit">Register</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class="button2 animated flipInY" type="reset" value="reset">Clear form</button></p>
            </div>  
        <div ng-switch-when="Members">
            <div class="animated fadeInDown">
                    <legend >Register new Member</legend>
                    <form  method="post" action="membersaction.php">

                        <label for="name">Name:</label><input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
                        <label for="surname">Surname:</label><input type="text" name="surname"><br><br>
                        <label for="telephone">Telephone:</label><input type="text" name="telephone"><br><br>
                        <label for="mobile">Mobile:</label><input type="text" name="mobile"><br><br>
                        <label for="email">Email:</label><input type="text" name="email"><br><br>

                    <p class="center"> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                <button class="button1 animated flipInX" type="submit" value="Submit">Register</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <button class="button2 animated flipInY" type="reset" value="reset">Clear form</button></p>
                    </form>
                    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `<nav>`, it looks like you are trying to use a method that would work with radio buttons, but that will not work with `<a>` elements. A method for using `<a>` to accomplish this would look like the following code:

```
<nav>
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li><a ng-click="updateMyVar('Home')" class="active" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="updateMyVar('Employees')" title="New Employee">Register new Employee</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="updateMyVar('Customers')" title="New Customer">Register new Customer</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="updateMyVar('Members')" title="New Member">Register new Member</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

And then in your controller, you could assign a starting value to `myVar` like this: `$scope.myVar = 'Home';` Then you would need to create a simple function:

```
$scope.updateMyVar = function(value) {
    $scope.myVar = value;
};
```

Comment: You could also skip the function and just use `ng-click="myVar = 'Home'"` etc, but I prefer to avoid putting logic in the view as much as possible.

Comment: I try it but this time the forms shown at the home page when i open the html file any suggest for this?

Comment: I see you are missing the closing `</div>` tag for the opening `<div ng-switch-when="Home">`. Perhaps this is related to the problem?

Comment: i saw this when i made changes and i closed it.

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the current problem. "this time the forms shown at the home page", does this mean you don't want to start with the home section open? If you don't want to start with a default page open, you can remove the `$scope.myVar = 'Home';` from your controller. You may want to replace it with `$scope.myVar = '';` just to ensure that none of the `ng-switch-when`s will be active.

Comment: I want to start with home, but at home appears all the forms and the menu doesn't work